# SharePoint Online error - One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing, feature-activation, sub-site

Today i ran in to an error "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields".

I activated the SharePoint Sever Publishing Infrastructure feature on that site collection along with a few other features and when i went in to create sub sites, i ran in to this error.

I tried following this document https://shipoint.com/2013/01/28/fixing-one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly-go-to-list-settings-page-to-delete-these-fields/, but issues is not resolved.

I run in to this error, when i try to use Team site template to create sub sites. for all other templates, no errors.

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? I'm having this same issue with several of my Site Collections but others seems to work fine. I have a ticket in with Microsoft but am not getting anywhere.

Comment: Are you using On prem or Online environment? If its Online, i had a ticket open with Microsoft, they ran some internal scripts and that resolved the issue. @DeborahH

Comment: @AXA240778 Did they tell you what it was? Im having the same issue...

Comment: Hello @TigerBear, MS support people ran some internal scripts and asked me to activate a few features through id. I would suggest to check if you have all system generated site content types and site columns. If not, you have to get them back by activating features (Powershell).